# Convert string to Date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string which represents a date. I want to store it in my dataBase but the problem is that in my database the attribute is defined as Date.
How would I properly convert my string into a Date so i can store it in my dataBase?
This is the way my string is: "fecha":"31 March 2023" .
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert any English textual datetime description into a unix timestamp with `strtotime()` function, and with the `date()` function you can format a unix timestamp. You can use both like that:

`$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($string));`

You can write this in a mutator, or you can check the Date Casting article in documentation:

[Date Casting docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)